# std::map::emplace() missing - outdated libraries?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use the C++11 emplace() function of a map, but NetBeans says a map has no such function. Looking at the headers, it's "right" - there is no mention (on Fedora 16) of emplace(). Which is all well and good, you know... but I kinda wanna use emplace().

How do I go about enabling this functionality? I know for a fact that it's existed since March of last year, probably earlier. A thorough search shows that emplace() basically only exists on my system in the headers for lists and vectors. Since there hasn't been a major revision of C++ in almost a decade, I'm not having any luck finding documentation on what to do if the libraries are "wrong".

Comment: @CharlesBailey: What he was trying to say was "since there was no major revision in the decade before c++11 I have no idea what people usually do in such situations"

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what version?

Comment: @David Brown GCC 4.6.2, though I'd like for it to also compile on my server (GCC 4.4.5).

Comment: if you're using g++, then libstdc++ (which g++ targets) has an outstanding PR to implement this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436

Comment: `libstdc++` (which gcc uses) is missing the emplace member for associative containers according to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x (search for 'emplace' on that page).

Comment: @David Brown Just stumbled upon that. Many expletives were involved. Just my luck to try and use the _one_ missing feature from that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your implementation doesn't support something, you have two choices:

- don't use the feature
- use another implementation which supports what you need.

The fact that there is a new standard doesn't widen the choices. In fact, it reduces it as you'll have additional difficulties in finding an implementation which supports everything that you want for each one your targets.

Note that for pure library things, the other implementation could be one you make: compatibility wrappers have an increased appearance in transition time. But you have to pay attention to name clashes effects (visibility of compatibility wrappers may add ambiguities to the code when the feature appears at its standard place).

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, the "GNU ISO C++ Library" just doesn't support the feature yet? Is there any way to check what version of the implementation I have, and if it's the latest? Someone, somewhere, has gotten it to work (without ever encountering this issue), I just don't know exactly what they were using.

Comment: @DigitalMan - A lot of the C++11 support is targeted at GCC 4.7 because there are serious API incompatibilities in the library.

Comment: @Bo Persson Thanks for the tip. From the [GCC 4.7 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), support for associative containers is partial - missing emplace members. _Just_ the emplace members. Insert all manner of expletives here.

Comment: I'm not sure but think libc++ is compatible with gcc, and it has these functions. libc++ seems to be the most complete implementation of the C++11 standard library at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.7 does not support this as there were unresolved issues with the standard at the time. It is implemented in 4.8 and above. You will need -std=c++11